# Can someone explain to me why this syntax using parentheses instead of curly brackets, adding comma and no more "return" in reduce method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, line-breaks, arrow-functions

I have a quick question, which I think related to line break or something, but I could not find an answer or post about. Here's an example using `reduce()` method.

This is what I usually do or see:

```
const unique = ['a','b','c','a''a','a','b'];

unique.reduce((acc, val)=> {acc[val]=(acc[val]||0)+1; return acc;}, {}); //{ a: 4, b: 2, c: 1 }
```

However, we can also use this syntax: remove the curly brackets  & `return`,  use parentheses instead and add a `,` before `acc`. Can someone explain to me this syntax?

```
unique.reduce((acc, val)=> (acc[val]=(acc[val]||0)+1, acc), {}); // { a: 4, b: 2, c: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because comma operator is used in your example. From [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

> The **comma operator** (`,`) evaluates each of its operands (from left to
> right) and returns the value of the last operand.

In `(acc[val]=(acc[val]||0)+1, acc)` comma does exactly that, it does left part first then returns `acc`.

Update:
Replacing parentheses with curly brackets will not work, because it doesn't comply with JS arrow function syntax. From [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) article on MDN:

> if the body requires additional lines of processing, you'll need to
> re-introduce brackets **PLUS the "return"**

so `return` is required with curly brackets, while with parentheses it's a concise arrow function which doesn't need `return`.

Comment: Oh I see, and why can't we use this **comma** operator (`,`) on curly brackets `{...}` and only on parentheses `(...)` ?